# Array to string conversion error in codeigniter views

Tags: php, codeigniter

My controller is as followes.

```
class Media extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent ::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    function get($folder_name)
    {
        $folder_name= "images/".$folder_name;
        $this->load->library("Folder_functions");
        $data = array("folders" => $this->folder_functions->folder_data($folder_name));
        //$data= $this->folder_functions->folder_data($folder_name);
        $this -> load -> view("display_folders", $data);
    }

}
```

Library is as follows

```
class Folder_functions
{
function __construct()
{
    $this->_ci =& get_instance();
    $this->_ci->load->model("folder_model");
}
function folder_data($path)
{
    $files1['name']= array();
    $files1['image']= array();
    $files1['name'] = scandir($path);
    unset($files1['name'][0]);
    unset($files1['name'][1]);
    $del_val= 'Thumbs.db';
    if(($key = array_search($del_val, $files1['name'])) !== false) 
    {
        unset($files1['name'][$key]);
    }

    foreach ($files1 as $key => $value) 
    {
        $results[] = $this->createObjectFromData($files1);
        //echo $files1['name'];
    }

    return $results;
}

function createObjectFromData($files)
{
    $files_obj = new Folder_Model();
    $files_obj -> set_name($files['name']);

    return $files_obj;
}

}
```

My views is as follows.

```
<?php

    foreach ($folders as $values) 
    {
        echo $values -> get_name();
        echo '|';
    }
?>
```

Model is as follows.

```
class Folder_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public $name;
    public $featured_image;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function set_name($folder_name)
    {
        $this -> name= $folder_name;
    }
    function set_featured_mage($image)
    {
        $this -> featured_image= $image;
    }

    function get_name()
    {
        return $this -> name;
    }
    function get_featured_mage()
    {
        return $this -> featured_image;
    }
}
```

?>

My problem is when I browse code-igniter/index.php/media/get/MyFolder' url I am getting an error "Array to string conversion" in views echo $values -> get_name(). How can I resolve this error. Please guide me.

Comment: You can try to dump `$folders` on your views.

Comment: Can you show us the `get_name` method of the `Folder_Model` class?

Comment: I added the model class.